# PHP and AWS - Retrieve EC2 Instance by Tag

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to retrieve EC2 instances by tag, through PHP. I can create the servers with tags, I can retrieve the servers with the tag data, but if what I want to do is retrieve by one of those tags, I'm having trouble finding examples.

This works:

```
if ($server_group != '') 
        $filter[] = array('Name' => 'tag-value','Value' => $server_group);

$response = $ec2->describe_instances(array('Filter' => $filter));
```

However, the problem is that it will find any tag with the value that I have assigned to the variable $server_group, whether it's the correct tag or not. I can of course simply be careful in how I assign tag values, but that's not bullet proof.

The alternative syntax is explained in the docs:

Example: To list just the resources that have been assigned tag Purpose=X, specify:

```
Filter.1.Name=tag:Purpose
Filter.1.Value.1=X
```

However, they give no examples. I thought it would be:

```
$filter[] = array('Filter.1.Name','Value' => 'tag:Group');
$filter[] = array('Name' => 'Filter.1.Value.1','Value' => $server_group);
```

However, this does not seem to work - I don't get anything back.

Has anyone done this? Have a working example they can share? I may not have been asking the correct question in Google - lots of examples of how to create the tags, but not how to retrieve by them.

Comment: Get the whole list and filter it locally

Answer (score 4):

We recently had need of writing a script to easily shut down all EC2 instances in our QA environment. We us an Environment tag to denote DEV, PRD, or QA environments. Here is a code snippet to demonstrate how we filtered via the API:

```
<?php
$aws = \Aws\Common\Aws::factory(array(
            'key'    => $key,
            'secret' => $secret,
            'region' => $region
        ));

$ec2 = $aws->get('ec2');
$args = array(
        'Filters' => array(
                array('Name' => 'tag:Environment',
                      'Values' => array('QA')
                )
        )
    );
$results = $ec2->describeInstances($args);
$reservations = $results['Reservations'];
foreach ($reservations as $reservation) {
    $instances = $reservation['Instances'];
    foreach ($instances as $instance) {

        $instanceName = '';
        foreach ($instance['Tags'] as $tag) {
            if ($tag['Key'] == 'Name') {
                $instanceName = $tag['Value'];
            }
        }

        if ($instance['State']['Name'] == \Aws\Ec2\Enum\InstanceStateName::RUNNING){
            $shutdownInstances['InstanceIds'][] = $instance['InstanceId'];
        }
    }

}
$results = $ec2->stopInstances($shutdownInstances);

$hipURL = "http://api.hipchat.com/v1/rooms/message?auth_token=$token&room_id=$roomId&from=$from&message=QA%20has%20been%20told%20to%20shutdown.";
$result = file_get_contents($hipURL);
```

We use this in a cron job to ensure QA gets shutdown each night as no one is using it overnight and it saves us a few dollars to not have it running.

To rewrite your Filter of finding all Purpose Tags with a value of X:

```
'Filters' => array(
  array('Name' => 'tag:Purpose',
        'Values' => array('X')
  )
)
```